# CSS full height equally spaced vertical list

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a full screen vertical navigation overlay.

I would like to make the `ul` container the full height of the page and then equally space each `li`. This list is not a fixed amount so looking for something that will dynamically resize.

Is FlexBox the way to go?

https://jsfiddle.net/w3hppLss/

```css
html, body{margin:0;padding:0;}
ul{list-style:none;height:100vh;}
li{background:grey;margin-bottom:5px;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try it! If you don't get the expected result, post the code here. (Spoiler: Yes, it is the way to go)

Answer (score 4):

use flexbox with `flex-direction:column` in `ul` and `flex:1` in `li`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  background:gray;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```